# gtsummary and lmerTest

Tags: lme4, gtsummary

I really appreciate gtsummary, but recently, this "classical" script including lmer() failed :

```
library(lmerTest) ; library(gtsummary) ; library(dplyr)
lmerTest::lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1 | Subject), sleepstudy) %>% tbl_regression()
```

This is the error message :

> Error in match.call() : ... used in a situation where it does not exist

I tried to re-install the 3 packages but the problem remains... Do you know why ?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow! For random effects or mixed effects models, I use the lme4 package. There are no issues with the lme4 model. Example Below!

```r
library(gtsummary) 
#> #BlackLivesMatter
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.5.0'

tbl <-
  lme4::lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1 | Subject), lme4::sleepstudy) %>% 
  tbl_regression()
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2021-10-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>